# Solution for a second order ODE with initial conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose you have a second order differential equation as
$$\ddot{\theta}+C\dot{\theta}+K\theta=0$$
Where $\theta(t)$ represents the  angle at time $t$. $K,C$ are constants

Then if $C^2-4K<0$ we have the solution as:
$\theta(t)=Ae^{-ct/2}\cos(\frac{\sqrt{4K-C^2}}{2}t)+Be^{-ct/2}\sin(\frac{\sqrt{4K-C^2}}{2}t)$.

This can be rewritten as $\theta(t)=De^{-ct/2}\sin(\frac{\sqrt{4K-C^2}}{2}t+E)$.

My question is, if we have two initial conditions as:
$\theta(0)=\frac{\pi}{3}radians$
$\dot{\theta}(0)=0$

Then how should I find the arbitary constants $D \& E$?  Because if I directly plug in the values you get:

$\theta(0)=D\sin(E)=\pi/3$
$\dot{\theta}(0)=D\sin(E)+D\frac{\sqrt{4K-C^2}}{2}\cos(E)=0$

Appreciate your help

Comment: Use some trig identity, to simplify second equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\dot{\theta}(0)=D\sin(E)+D\frac{\sqrt{4K-C^2}}{2}\cos(E)=0$$

Divide by $D \sin E$:
$$\frac{\sqrt{4K-C^2}}{2} \dfrac {\cos E}{\sin E}=-1$$
$$\tan E= -\frac{\sqrt{4K-C^2}}{2}$$

Comment: Thank you. And a quick question. In my first equation (for $\theta(0)$) there is nothing wrong with writing the right-hand side as $\pi/3$ radians. Isn't it?

Comment: You're welcome.Nothing wrong... @Charith  Once  you have the angle E you deduce D from the first equation. $D=\pi /(3\sin E)$

Comment: Sounds good. Thanks